# json_contains function not working the same in localhost and server

Tags: mysql, json, database, mariadb

I have a table that has two columns one is needle and the second is haystack

needle column contains string values
haystack contains json array values

i need to search my table for all records that has the needle value in haystack json array

i have used the json_contains function like that

```
select * from table_name where JSON_CONTAINS(table_name.haystack, JSON_QUOTE(table_name.needle))
```

and it worked properly in localhost
but in the server it's not working as expected

but if i put a plain value as the needle it works fine in server like that i mean

```
select * from table_name where JSON_CONTAINS(table_name.haystack, 'أحمد')
```

those are the details of local and server from phpmyadmin home page

local

[image: local]

server

[image: server]

Comment: This is a good example of why we should not think of MariaDB as compatible with MySQL. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have been adding their own changes independently, with no guarantee of compatibility. You should always use the same product on your local development environment as you will eventually deploy to, so you avoid surprises like this. Also read the documentation for the product you are going to use.

Comment: While the visual of `json_quote` look the same in both, compare the actual hex output of [MariaDB-10.3 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=82abbf59cbe0a456f8f80134c48c53e7) and the equal [MySQL-8.0 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=82abbf59cbe0a456f8f80134c48c53e7). So what @BillKarwin said, use the same version for both and avoid surprises. JSON especially is implemented quite differently in MySQL vs MariaDB despite a seemly similar SQL layer (in some json bits).

Comment: Apart from the "use the same product / version on both instances" topic already rightfully raised by others you may also want to make sure to use current releases where possible. With MySQL 8.0.27 you are using a rather current release series, while the MariaDB 10.3 series is already rather old, and reaching its end-of-life next spring. The current top-of-the-line MariaDB release series is MariaDB 10.8, and it contains quite a few improvements in the JSON area ...